# Reflection on load in to new app domain

Tags: c#

Can we load a assembly in **reflection-only** context into a **new** app domain?

I could not find anything related to this.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: There is no method in AppDomain object to load it with reflection-only context.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to the correct resource